# How to create modal for wysiwyg for url and image in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wysiwyg, execcommand

Recently I am trying to create a wysiwyg editor with react. I almost created basic functionality but now I am stuck with some functionality such as adding link, image, table etc.
I can add this functionality with prompt() method. But, I want if someone click link button then a popup will appear and user can set the url for specific selected text. Also want this kind of features for other buttons such as image, table etc.

Here is the demo link: https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-lamport-e9zzb?file=/public/index.html